# How can I link pd-for-ios with my objective-c project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, puredata

I've been following this tutorial for [libPd for iOS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l5GQqCDmBZY) and halfway through i get some errors saying:

> No such file or directory: '~/pd-for-ios/libpd/pure-data/src/d_dac.c'
>
> No such file or directory: '~/pd-for-ios/libpd/pure-data/src/d_array.c'
>
> No such file or directory: '~/pd-for-ios/libpd/pure-data/src/d_ctl.c'
>
> No such file or directory: '~/pd-for-ios/libpd/pure-data/src/d_arithmetic.c'

Those files, on inspection, are non existent, but Xcode keeps searching for them and I don't know if i should create them or get them somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, at first I used instructions in [this page](https://github.com/libpd/libpd):

```
git clone https://github.com/libpd/libpd.git
cd libpd
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Which for some reason didn't work, now, after trying [this](https://github.com/libpd/pd-for-ios/wiki/ios):

```
git clone --recursive git://github.com/libpd/pd-for-ios.git
```

everything's alright.